# Azure Function to Update Table Storage entity - CloudTable.Execute not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm starting out using Azure and c# and I'm attempting to use Table Storage - and using an Azure Function to update entitys in the table. My code is as follows:

```
 #r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json; 
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, CloudTable lookupTable)
{
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    string partitionKey = data.Society;
    string rowKey = data.ConnectionDetails.Environment; 
    string newConnection = data.ConnectionDetails.Connection; 

    TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve<SocietyConnectionDetails>(partitionKey, rowKey); 
    TableResult result = lookupTable.Execute(operation);
    SocietyConnectionDetails societyConnectionDetails = (SocietyConnectionDetails)result.Result; 

    societyConnectionDetails.Connection = newConnection; 
    operation = TableOperation.Replace(societyConnectionDetails); 
    lookupTable.Execute(operation);
}

public class SocietyConnectionDetails : TableEntity
{
    public string Connection {get; set;}
}
```

But the errors im getting are as follows:

```
2020-02-25T10:33:16.956 [Error] run.csx(17,38): error CS1061: 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no accessible extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2020-02-25T10:33:16.984 [Error] run.csx(22,17): error CS1061: 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no accessible extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2020-02-25T10:33:17.011 [Error] run.csx(8,47): error CS0161: 'Run(HttpRequest, CloudTable)': not all code paths return a value
```

I can see that the issue is happening when im attempting to 'Execute' my Table Operations... this might be a relatively straight forward problem but I'm struggling to work out why this wouldn't be working...

Thanks for any help..

Comment: From your description, you are using crx. So you need to add a file to install the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your error.

Like this:

[image]

Solution is add a function.proj file to your function.
[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then the error should disappear.
(If you dont do this. the compilation step will not success.)
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've added the function.csproj file but unfortunately still getting the came error. Basically its giving me what you have in the last image above then this: 2020-02-25T12:41:17.936 [Information] D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.109\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0. [D:\local\Temp\e0310930-cfd5-4e9b-8991-6a8e0c468f04\function.proj]

Comment: And then compilation errors: 
2020-02-25T12:41:18.292 [Error] run.csx(24,17): error CS1061: 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'execute' and no accessible extension method 'execute' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2020-02-25T12:41:18.320 [Error] run.csx(10,47): error CS0161: 'Run(HttpRequest, CloudTable)': not all code paths return a value
2020-02-25T12:41:18.349 [Error] Executed 'Functions.HttpLookUpUpdate' (Failed, Id=90b0193c-bccb-41a6-8acd-2359bcaa1ac4)

Comment: @CJL1992 Change the TargetFramework to netcoreapp2.2.

Comment: Cheers, I changed it there now and it has created the projects.assets.json etc. Only issues now are the compilation errors above

Comment: Let me know if you have any ideas about what might be causing the compilation errors - please

Comment: @CJL1992 I'm trying to solve this problem, and I will notify you immediately if I solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm working on it as well and will update it I find a solution

Comment: @CJL1992 I think you need to use async method. ExecuteAsync() instead of Execute()

Comment: Fantastic, I changed `TableResult result = lookupTable.Execute(operation);` -> to -> `TableResult result = await lookupTable.ExecuteAsync(operation);` and then `lookupTable.Execute(operation);` -> to -> `await lookupTable.ExecuteAsync(operation);` and it now works as desired - thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the Azure Functions runtime 2, and in this case the problem is related to your references. You should reference the nuget package *Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage* and ensure it is installed in your function, according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table?tabs=csharp#azure-storage-sdk-version-in-functions-1x) in Microsoft's documentation.